# iOS: Change UITableViewCell's height after resizing view(with Autolayouts)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I have a `UITableViewController` with static cell's count. I want to divide the `UITableView` into cells of equal height.

If I had a static `UITableView`. I will do it this way:

```
tableviewcontroller.tableView.rowHeight = tableviewcontroller.tableView.frame.size.height/cellsCount;
```

But this is a bad idea if I resize my view with Autolayouts dynamically.

I want to do something like this
[image]

Comment: why don't you use table view data source -> height for row with an unique size return?

Comment: I don't need this. All my cells are equal height.

Comment: if you use dynamic tableView you need to implement this data source and if the project is autolayout, return UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Comment: if you use static table so what the exactly problem is?

Comment: cells not resize  automaticly with resizing tableviewcontroller.tableView.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    return yourCellHeight;
}
```

and eventually if needed

```
[tableView ReloadData];
```